# How to create relationship between two tables mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables:

topics table:

```
CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topicId` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `details` text,
  `dayPosted` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userImage` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

comments table:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `commentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topicId` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `comments` text,
  `commentDate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`commentId`),
  KEY `topicId_idx` (`topicId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`topicId` column is common in both the tables and I want to create relationship between both the tables. The problem is topicId is not a primary key(I can make it unique though)

Or do I create a third table like `topics_comments` and have both:

1. topicId as foreign key relationship to topicId in topics with
   cascade on update and delete
2. commentId as foreign key relationship to commentId in comments with
   cascade on update and delete

Actual scenario is I have blog posting site where users will comment on that blog where each blog topic has a `topicId` and each user comment has `commentId` and now I have create tables based on condition:

1. Each blog topic can have multiple comments
2. when blog topic is deleted, all the comments on that blog topic must
   be deleted
3. Users who posted comments can later delete them or edit them

I am using mysql with **spring boot** and **spring jpa**

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class TopicBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "topicId")
    private String topicId;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "details")
    private String details;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "userImage")
    private String userImage;
    @Column(name = "dayPosted")
    private String dayPosted;

//Getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stick to your current schema and still be able to define working mappings with JPA. Here is the set-up that worked for me in local environement(only the important bits here):

**Topics**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class Topic implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "topicId")
    private Integer topicId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "topic", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Comment> comments;
```

**Comments**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "commentId")
    private Integer commentId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "topicId", referencedColumnName = "topicId")
    private Topic topic;
```

Just remember to add unique index on TOPICS.topicsId.

Regarding the linking table scenario, well i would use it if you are really have as:

- Your schema design seems to be explicitly uni-directional where Topics have comments and comment has only one owning topic. So this would be kind of a logical flaw.
- IF you would be querying from comments and joining to topics, you would need additional join, which could slow down on performance
- Getting the Topic for a Comment using JPA would be a bit awkward because you would be getting a List of Topics and then you would need to explicitly get the first entry.
- You would end up with obsolete / redundant topicId column in your Topics table.

The plus is of course that you would be joining properly, that is using primary keys, so the decision is up to you. Here are the mappings:

**Topics**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class Topic implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

     @ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(name="COMMON",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TOPIC_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COMMENT_ID"))
    private List<Comment> comments;
```

**Comments**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "commentId")
    private Integer commentId;

    @ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(name="COMMON",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COMMENT_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TOPIC_ID"))
    private Topic topic;
```

Comment: Have added info if you want to go for the linking table strategy with some thoughts of mine. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much. I was confused whether to use JPA `@join` annotations or create a relationship between tables in mysql.

Comment: Both are workable. I would personally stay with your current schema though and and map with option 1. But hey decision is yours

Comment: `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "topic", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Comment> comments;` Does this mean one topic can have many comments or its the opposite?

Comment: I have `comments` column inside `comments` table not in `topics` table.  So I would change the annotation to this?? `@ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(name="topics",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COMMENT_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TOPIC_ID"))
    @Column(name = "comments")
    private String comments;`

Comment: But comments is just a basic text column.. you do not use that for joining (you should not at least)